# Suma de dos valores jquery utilizando foreach en php

Tags: php, jquery

estoy trabado con un problema que no he podido resolver, estoy utilizando un formulario y en la vista tengo un foreach recorriendo un array. El problema que tengo es que necesito retornar el total de la suma entre el valor-a y valor-b y el resultando en un input suma_total pero el valor se repite debido a que estoy seleccionando es la clase, he intentado colocar el boton que realiza la accion por fuera del bucle pero no me ha funcionado. adjunto mi codigo php y jquery. Agradezco la ayuda

```
<?php

//Get work order
$workerItem = "work_id";
$workerValue = $_GET["workId"];

$worker = WorkordersController::ctlWorkShow($workerItem,$workerValue);

//Decode json string
$workersList = json_decode($worker["work_workers"],true);

foreach ($workersList as $key => $value) {

    $item = "user_id";
    $value_2 = $value["id"];

    $response = UsersController::ctlUserShow($item, $value_2);

    echo '<div class="row" style="padding:5px 15px">
            <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-right: 0px" >
              <div class="input-group">

                <input type="text" style="font-size: 12px" class="form-control newWorkerName"    value="'.($key+1).'" readonly >
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-3" >
               <div class="input-group">
                   <input type="text" style="font-size: 12px" class="form-control valor-a"  value="" >
               </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-xs-3" >
               <div class="input-group">
                   <input type="text" style="font-size: 12px" class="form-control valor-b"  value="" >
               </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 0px">
               <div class="input-group">
                   <input type="text" style="font-size: 12px" class="form-control suma_total" value="" readonly>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>';
}

echo '<button class="btn btn-success btnCalcular" style="font-size: 11px">Calcular</button>';
?>

$(".btnCalcular").click(function () {

  event.preventDefault();

  var valorA = $(".valor-a").val();

  var valorB = $(".valor-b").val();

  var total = $(".suma_total");

  var suma = Number(valorA)+Number(valorB);

  total.val(suma);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes identificar el contexto donde está cada botón, de esta forma podrás seleccionar los campos asociados al botón pulsado y así poder sumarlos para obtener el resultado deseado.

He recreado un ejemplo funcional de tu codigo tratando en lo posible hacer los mínimos cambios posibles para lograr el resultado deseado.

```js
$(".btnCalcular").click(function () {

  event.preventDefault();

  var $elm = $(event.target.closest("div"));

  var valorA = $elm.find(".valor-a").val();

  var valorB = $elm.find(".valor-b").val();

  var total = $elm.find(".suma_total");

  var suma = Number(valorA)+Number(valorB);

  total.val(suma);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" style="padding:5px 15px">
 <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-right: 0px" >
  <div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" style="font-size: 12px" class="form-control newWorkerName"    value="1" readonly >
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-3" >
  <div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" style="font-size: 12px" class="form-control valor-a"  value="" >
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-3" >
  <div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" style="font-size: 12px" class="form-control valor-b"  value="" >
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 0px">
  <div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" style="font-size: 12px" class="form-control suma_total" value="" readonly>
  </div>
 </div>
 <button class="btn btn-success btnCalcular" style="font-size: 11px">Calcular</button>
</div>

<div class="row" style="padding:5px 15px">
 <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-right: 0px" >
  <div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" style="font-size: 12px" class="form-control newWorkerName"    value="2" readonly >
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-3" >
  <div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" style="font-size: 12px" class="form-control valor-a"  value="" >
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-3" >
  <div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" style="font-size: 12px" class="form-control valor-b"  value="" >
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 0px">
  <div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" style="font-size: 12px" class="form-control suma_total" value="" readonly>
  </div>
 </div>
 <button class="btn btn-success btnCalcular" style="font-size: 11px">Calcular</button>
</div>
```

Espero esto te sirva ;))...

Y recuerda aceptar (tildar) la respuesta que más se corresponda a la solución del problema.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda me funciono perfectamente !